# SSH version shows older one after upgrading

Tags: ssh, openssh

I've upgraded OpenSSH version in my Ubuntu 18.04 server to 7.9 to fix User enumeration vulnerability. 
When I enter the following command, the output is:

```
ssh -V

OpenSSH_7.9p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
```

But when I run telnet on port 22 it shows Ubuntu 18.04's default ssh version

```
telnet localhost 22

Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
```

When I run

```
ssh -v localhost

debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
```

Which means the vulnerability is not fixed yet.

1. Appreciate if anyone can explain why it shows two different versions as (local version & remote protocol version)?
2. If OpenSSH is not upgraded properly, how I can actually upgrade the OpenSSH?

Comment: `openssh-client` and `openssh-server` are two different packages? How did you do the upgrade?

Comment: Downloaded it from https://cdn.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-7.9p1.tar.gz

   `cd openssh-7.9p1`
   `sudo apt-get update`
   `sudo apt-get install build-essential`
   `sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev`
   `apt-get install openssl openssl-dev`
   `apt install libssl1.0-dev`
   `./configure  --sysconfdir=/etc/ssh`
   `make`
   `make install`

Comment: Which CVE were you trying to patch?

Comment: Your output seems to show that you upgraded your openssh *client*, not server.

Comment: @user535733 I was trying to fix Username enumeration Vulnerability. And oh I see, then I should download openssh-server right?

Comment: If you have the CVE number, you can check the [Ubuntu Security Team](http://security.ubuntu.com) database - maybe you were already running a patched package, and all your effort wasted. Maybe, maybe not. But that should usually be your first stop when checking on a vuln. Your non-Ubuntu download won't get automatic security upgrades. OpenSSH gets a lot of security attention and fairly frequent patches.

Comment: Did you `sudo service ssh restart`?

Comment: @user535733 This is the CVE number - CVE-2018-15473. According to this forum discussion, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/1794629: The vulnerability seems to be fixed in `1:7.6p1-4ubuntu0.1`. I have been reported this bug when I ran Qualys scan to detect PCI DSS vulnerabilities. Seems like Qualys scan is blindly asserting OpenSSH version against 7.8 :/

Comment: @waltinator yes I did restart the server and ssh several times.

Comment: See https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2018/CVE-2018-15473.html for the Ubuntu Security Team's notes (seems a client issue, not server), and the earliest version of the package that includes the patch for each release of Ubuntu. It's not surprising that third-party scanners give false positives on already-patched packages.